# Transfer multilevel element XML to one level

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have a xml with multiple items, which are Multilevel BOM (in the example 2 items, with both three levels). I need this to convert to xml with each record only the father and the Childs (first record of each item has no father).
We use XSLT 1.0 and we can't use Muenchian grouping because the processor in use don't know the key function.
I hope someone can help me out.

XML example:

```
            <Items>
               <level01>
                <itemcode>L100</itemcode>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
                <whs>30</whs>
                <level02>
                    <row>
                        <itemcode>L201</itemcode>
                        <quantity>5</quantity>
                        <whs>02</whs>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <itemcode>L202</itemcode>
                        <quantity>8</quantity>
                        <whs>01</whs>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <itemcode>L203</itemcode>
                        <quantity>1</quantity>
                        <whs>01</whs>
                        <level03>
                            <row>
                                <itemcode>L301</itemcode>
                                <quantity>1</quantity>
                                <whs>01</whs>
                            </row>
                            <row>
                                <itemcode>L302</itemcode>
                                <quantity>1</quantity>
                                <whs>01</whs>
                            </row>
                        </level03>
                    </row>
                </level02>
            </level01>
            <level01>
                <itemcode>M100</itemcode>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
                <whs>30</whs>
                <level02>
                    <row>
                        <itemcode>M201</itemcode>
                        <quantity>3</quantity>
                        <whs>01</whs>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <itemcode>M202</itemcode>
                        <quantity>2</quantity>
                        <whs>01</whs>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <itemcode>M203</itemcode>
                        <quantity>2</quantity>
                        <whs>01</whs>
                        <level03>
                            <row>
                                <itemcode>M301</itemcode>
                                <quantity>1</quantity>
                                <whs>01</whs>
                            </row>
                            <row>
                                <itemcode>M302</itemcode>
                                <quantity>1</quantity>
                                <whs>01</whs>
                            </row>
                        </level03>
                    </row>
                </level02>
            </level01>
          </Items>
```

desired result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Items>
    <Item>
        <itemcode>L100</itemcode>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <whs>02</whs>
    </Item> 
    <Item>
        <father>L100</father>
        <itemcode>L201</itemcode>
        <quantity>5</quantity>
        <whs>02</whs>
    </Item> 
    <item>
        <father>L100</father>
        <itemcode>L202</itemcode>
        <quantity>8</quantity>
        <whs>01</whs>
    </item>
    <item>
        <father>L100</father>
        <itemcode>L203</itemcode>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <whs>01</whs>
    </item>
    <item>
        <father>L203</father>
        <itemcode>L301</itemcode>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <whs>01</whs>
    </item>
    <item>
        <father>L203</father>
        <itemcode>L302</itemcode>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <whs>01</whs>
    </item>
</Items>
<Items>
    <item>
        <itemcode>M100</itemcode>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <whs>02</whs>
    </item>
    <item>
        <father>M100</father>
        <itemcode>M201</itemcode>
        <quantity>3</quantity>
        <whs>01</whs>
    </item>
    <item>
        <father>M100</father>
        <itemcode>M202</itemcode>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
        <whs>01</whs>
    </item>
    <item>
        <father>M100</father>
        <itemcode>M203</itemcode>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
        <whs>01</whs>
    </item>
    <item>
        <father>M203</father>
        <itemcode>M301</itemcode>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <whs>01</whs>
    </item>
    <item>
        <father>M203</father>
        <itemcode>M302</itemcode>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <whs>01</whs>
    </item>
</items>
```

---

```
<?bpc.pltype.out bpm.pltype=xml?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:b1e="urn:com.sap.b1i.sim:b1event" xmlns:b1ie="urn:com.sap.b1i.sim:b1ievent" xmlns:b1im="urn:com.sap.b1i.sim:b1imessage" xmlns:bfa="urn:com.sap.b1i.bizprocessor:bizatoms" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:jdbc="urn:com.sap.b1i.adapter:jdbcadapter" xmlns:js="com.sap.b1i.bpc_tools.Javascript" xmlns:rev="urn:com.sap.b1i.adapter:revaadapter" xmlns:rfc="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions" xmlns:sim="urn:com.sap.b1i.sim:entity" xmlns:utils="com.sap.b1i.bpc_tools.Utilities"
    xmlns:vpf="urn:com.sap.b1i.vplatform:entity" xmlns:xci="urn:com.sap.b1i.xcellerator:intdoc" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="b1e b1ie b1im bfa jdbc js rfc utils xci vpf exslt sim rev" b1e:force="" b1ie:force="" b1im:force="" bfa:force="" jdbc:force=""
    js:force="" rfc:force="" utils:force="" xci:force="" vpf:force="" exslt:force="" sim:force="" rev:force="">
    <?prodver 1.0.0?>
    <!--<xsl:include href="../../com.sap.b1i.dev.repository/IDE/init.xsl" />-->
    <xsl:variable name="msg" select="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/vpf:Payload[./@Role='S']" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Msg xmlns="urn:com.sap.b1i.vplatform:entity">
            <xsl:copy-of select="/vpf:Msg/@*" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Header" />
            <Body>
                <xsl:copy-of select="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/*" />
                <Payload Role="X" id="999999">
                    <xsl:call-template name="transform" />
                </Payload>
            </Body>
        </Msg>
    </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="transform">

This is the space we usually add our code

    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this? I don't see any need for grouping here, just a simple template that processes the tree from top to bottom. -- Also, what kind of processor you have that "don't know the key function"?? Key is an integral part of XSLT 1.0; if your processor does not support it, then it is not an XSLT processor at all. What other parts of the XSLT 1.0 specification it does not support?

Comment: P.S The example input is not a well-formed XML document (no single root element).

Comment: (I add the root-element)

Comment: See this answer on your question: https://answers.sap.com/questions/508588/does-xslkey-work-in-b1if.html . Maybe it sound strange, but I have to deal with it. I need the new structure to build an insert query to the database. The problem with the child nodes is they haven't a reference to their parent node. So a for-each with condition is not possible (I think) and I don't have not enough experience to solve this with templates.

Comment: (I need to insert the father into the father table and the child's into the child table. The father is the key between the two tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, I see no need for grouping here. The only complication is the irregularity of your input (no `row` wrapper at the top level) and of the output (no `father` element for the items with no parent). Otherwise this could be even simpler.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Items">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="level01"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="level01">
    <Item>
        <xsl:copy-of select="itemcode|quantity|whs"/>
    </Item> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/row"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
    <Item>
        <father>
            <xsl:value-of select="(ancestor::*/itemcode)[last()]"/>
        </father>
        <xsl:copy-of select="itemcode|quantity|whs"/>
    </Item> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/row"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do note that the output is somewhat different from the one in your question: the `Items` element is the root element of the entire output tree. Without this, you would receive an XML fragment instead of a well-formed XML document.

If you want an *additional* wrapper for each main branch, change the template matching `level01`  to:

```
<xsl:template match="level01">
    <Branch>
        <Item>
            <xsl:copy-of select="itemcode|quantity|whs"/>
        </Item> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*/row"/>
    </Branch>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, this works good and help me one step further to understand templates. I test it in a a generic tool. But one lost question. The SAP tool generate the first part of the stylesheet and each process step you create, the xml of the previous process step will copied (I guess you understand when you read the code below). So the new process step already create the template. I tried to give your templates a name and placed them below the generated template and call your templates from here, without succes.

Comment: I can't find the possibility to add the code, so I try it by answer the question.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with your tool and I don't know how to help you.